# Где заканчивается причастный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть три похожих предложения. Заканчивается ли причастный оборот до предлога "для" или уже после него?
 1. Распространяется на жесткие и компенсирующие линзы, применяемые в химической и нефтехимической промышленностях для арматуры, соединительных частей и трубопроводов с линзовым уплотнением на Ру 200—1000 кгс/см2 и Dy 6—200 мм с температурой от минус 50 до плюс 510 °С. 
 2. Арматура, имеющая номинальный диаметр более 25 для оборудования с рабочей средой группы 1. 
 3. Арматура, имеющая номинальный диаметр более 200 для трубопроводов, предназначенных для жидкостей и используемых для рабочих сред группы 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ваших предложениях предлог ***для*** входит в причастный оборот и отделяется вместе с ним запятой. Иначе нарушится синтаксическая связь. 
Ср.: ...применяемые в химической и нефтехимической промышленностях(***,***) для арматуры. В этом предложении причастный оборот отделенной запятой имеет самостоятельное значение. Для арматуры - никак не связывается со всем предложением и является избыточным. 
Запятая во втором предложении вносит неясность в предложение, придавая незаконченность. Ср. : ...имеющая номинальный диаметр более 25 - что? Предложение с предлогом  становится синтаксически независимым и опять-таки неполным.